# Difference between resource.save() with callback and $promise in ngResource using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, race-condition, angular-ui-router, ngresource

This is my factory:

```
// Factory
app.factory('BuildingListService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return {
    selectBuilding: function(building, callback) {
        return $resource(window.appSettings.context+'/requests/building')
                   .save(building, callback);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Now, I **thought** that these two bits of code should behave the same:

**First:**

```
 $scope.selectBuilding= function(building) {
     BuildingListService.selectBuilding(building, function() {
         $state.go('requests.detail.analystReview');
     });
 });
```

**Second:**

```
 $scope.selectBuilding= function(building) {
    BuildingListService.selectBuilding(building).$promise.then(function() {
       $state.go('requests.detail.analystReview');
    });
 };
```

**However** in the first state I get a race condition where the server has not finished the request prior to changing state. I am a little confused as to why that is. The second way I mentioned has no such issue. Is there a reason that the `$state.go('requests.detail.analystReview');` would be called in the first bit of code **before** the server has finished? This one has really confused me.

Also note that solution one is working fine in IE and FireFox, I am starting to suspect a caching issue

**Update:**
So I have solved my issue, the issue was caching related, IE caches a little aggressively sometimes I should have see that. However I am not sure why the first call would make IE more prone to caching the requests than the second. Thank you to anyone that looked at this.

Comment: Why aren't you using BuildingListService in your first example?

Comment: Sorry I typed it from memory and did it wrong, that was really silly, I am very sure this is not a syntactical issue. Also, solution one WORKS in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that your first example isn't relying on `BuildingListService` at all? Shouldn't it be something like this?:

```
$scope.selectBuilding = function(building) {
  BuildingListService.selectBuilding(building, function() {
    $state.go('requests.detail.analystReview');
  });
};
```